# Maior/Menor valor - Vetores em C

Tags: c, array

To tentando fazer um algoritimo para achar o maior e menor valor de um vetor escrito pelo usuario. Comecei a fazer a parte do maior valor pra pensar na do menor valor depois.
Nao sei o que fiz de errado aqui, mas nao está achando o maior valor.

O ERRO:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```c
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
      int vetor[7];
      int ma=0, me, a, i; 
      
      ma=vetor[0];
      me=vetor[0];
        
      for(i=0;i<7;i++){
        printf("Digite o %dº número: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
      }
       
      for(i = 1; i < 7; i++){
        if(vetor[i] > ma){
            ma=vetor[i];
        }

      }
          for(i = 1; i < 7; i++){
        if(vetor[i] == ma){
            a++;
        }
        

      }
      
      
      printf("Maior numero: %d", ma);
        
    }
```

Comment: Teu segundo for deveria começar em zero

Answer (score -1):

Conforme o comentário do Leonardo, seu laço `for` estava errado.

Também, você estava utilizando dois loops para fazer a comparação, o que é desnecessário, visto que você pode fazer as comparações no mesmo loop.

Abaixo um exemplo.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int vetor[7];
  int i = 0; 
  int maior;
  int menor;
    
  for(;i<7;i++){
    printf("Digite o %dº número: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
  }
  maior = vetor[0];
  menor = vetor[0];
  for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    if(vetor[i] > maior){
      maior=vetor[i];
    }
    if (vetor[i] < menor) {
      menor = vetor[i];
    }
  }
  
  printf("Maior numero: %d\n", maior);
  printf("Menor numero: %d", menor);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigada! Me ajudou muito!

Comment: Neste caso, lembre-se de aceitar a resposta.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int vetor[7], i = 0, maior, menor;
    
  for(;i<7;i++){
    printf("Digite o %dº número: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
  }
  maior = vetor[0];
  menor = vetor[0];
  for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    if(vetor[i] > maior){
      maior=vetor[i];
    }else{
      menor = vetor[i];
    }
  }
  printf("Maior numero: %d\n", maior);
  printf("Menor numero: %d", menor);
  return 0;
}
```

Apenas para complementar a resposta com um detalhe sobre o uso do *if* e *else*